# mysqli y php no funciona la consulta

Tags: php, mysql, sql

quiero mostrar por pantalla una cierta cantidad de "productos", yo cree una serie de cartas de bootstrap para guardar la información ahi.
Genero mi conexión (Aclaro que la conexión esta perfecta):

```
<?php
   $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "**", "pampa");
   mysqli_select_db("pampa",$conexion);
?>
```

y aqui la consulta que quiero mostrar:

```
<?php  

                $consulta = "SELECT * FROM productos";
                if ($resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)) {
                    /* obtener el array de objetos */
                    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_row()) {
                                        echo '<div class="carta">';  
                                        echo '<div class="sugerencias _hot"><span class="hot">HOT</span></div>';
                                        echo '<div class="imagenCarta">';
                                        echo '<img class="imgCARD" src='.$fila[imagen].'>';
                                        echo '</div>';
                                        echo '<div class="cuerpo">';
                                        echo '<div class="titulo">'.$fila[titulo].'</div>';
                                        echo '<div class="info">'.$fila[descripcion].'</div>';
                                        echo '<div class="rec">Por dia: <span style="color:#39b540;font-size:15px;font-weight: 300;">'.$fila[precio].'</span></div>';
                                        echo '</div></div>'; 
                    }

                    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
                    $resultado->close();
                }
               ?>
```

El problema es que el resultado que me muestra es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, me da el mismo resultado:

Comment: ¿Qué resultado obtiene si accede mediante el indice numérico del array ? solo de esa forma debería acceder , es decir `$fila[0]` , o  `$fila[1]` dependiendo de la columna que desee recuperar.

Comment: puedes hacer un var_dump($resultado) y editar tu respuesta? Para poder ver qué te devuelve la BD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías revisar como es el orden de tus columnas, para saber cómo mostrar los datos, si el orden fuera imagen, titulo y descripcion podrías acceder a ellos así;

```
 echo '<img class="imgCARD" src='.$fila[0].'>';
 echo '<div class="titulo">'.$fila[1].'</div>';
 echo '<div class="info">'.$fila[2].'</div>';
```

También podrías realizar un `var_dump` de `filas`, así sabrás como se están devolviendo los datos.

Espero sea de tu utilidad.

Comment: Funcione perfecto!! Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para que funcione en la forma en que lo planteas, en tu ciclo, en lugar de usar la función *fetch_row()* debes usar **fetch_assoc()** que te devuelve un arreglo por fila; en dicho arreglo se asocia el nombre del campo con el índice de un elemento del arreglo.

En mi opinión, la forma en como lo estás haciendo es más práctica porque hace tu código más legible, y si lo usas por referencia numérica es más difícil puesto que tienes que conocer el orden de los campos con base en el query que hagas.

Más información sobre esta función en http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente la variable $fila[imagen] no está devolviendo lo que esperas.
Y sin ver el código o lo que devuelve la base de datos, me imagino que esto

```
echo '<img class="imgCARD" src='.$fila[imagen].'>';
```

debería ser algo como esto

```
echo '<img class="imgCARD" src="path_to_img/'.$fila[imagen].'">';
```

Únicamente he añadido las comillas dobles para que el src quede entrecomillado, aparte de añadir el path_to_img que no será necesario si la variable $file[imagen] te devuelve /ruta/hasta/la/imagen.jpg.
Si esa variable sólo devuelve "imagen.jpg", necesitarás ponerle toda la ruta hasta la carpeta que contiene la imagen que quieres mostrar.